# Is it good practice to pass requests/responses to other classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, request, response

I am creating a helper class to manage cookies, which brings up the point is where to add the cookies to the response? At the moment, I am using the helper class to just create a cookie and return it to the controller where it then attaches the cookie to the response. What if I wanted to edit or delete cookies? Would it be sensible to pass in the reponse to the helper class and let it do the attach/delete, thus abstracting all the cookie handling away from the controller?

Comment: Can I answer with another question? "Why not? Any visible drawback?"

Comment: Not any visible drawback but I feel that responses/requests should sit at the controller layer. Thinking about it some more, I need to pass in by reference correct?

Comment: It's a reference type so you simply can't pass it by value (but if your question is "do I need `ref`?" then answer is _no_). I don't feel (but it's pretty opinion based) any "smell" to delegate something to a class external to your controller. It's pretty unrelated (unless you need to call controller's methods) even if this separation is pretty arbitrary (to simplify controller itself and to reuse such code). Moreover do not forget you can always have a base abstract controller where you put such helper methods and you'll derive your controllers from the appropriate base.